# ReferenceError: $ is not defined when making Ajax api call in asp.net razor page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am making a simple Ajax call to `api/news` in asp.net razor page file. API is working fine as it show all data when i access access it `https://localhost:44364/api/news`
[image]

i keep getting `ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and debugger points to `$(document).ready(function () {` line of code.

I even use simplified version of ajax call which is also mentioned below but i keep getting the same error.

When i remove `.ajax` call or comment all ajax error goes away.

Not sure what exactly is this error pointing to

```
<script>

        function loadNewsData() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/api/news",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    var table = $("<table><tr><th>Details</th></tr>");

                    table.append("<tr><td>Title:</td><td>" + result["NewsHeading"] + "</td></tr>");
                    table.append("</table>");

                    $("#message").html(table);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadNewsData();
    });
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

        function loadNewsData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/news",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log('Error ${error}');
                }
            });
        }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadNewsData();
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ is not a dom variable. It is a third party library called jquery. you must add
the below script before using $ object.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

for [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide)

Comment: @Learning try put it on head section, or just before the first time you execute the ajax.

Comment: Its seems issue is will placement of ajax file as al js files are at the end of the page and as part of `_Layout.cshtml` when added jquery cdn reference to news page also it worked. Not sure why